# Is there any Prolog parser for TSPLIB and / or SAT format?

Tags: prolog

Are there any parsers written in Prolog for either the [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) or the [suggested satisfiability format](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~hoos/SATLIB/Benchmarks/SAT/satformat.ps)?

(The second link is to a PostScript file)

Comment: [This link](http://www.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/groups/comopt/software/TSPLIB95/) works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider reasing TSPLIB with existing C/C++ tools and then use the SWI-Prolog C library (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/clib.html) to call these tools from Prolog.